# How to make Restlet class handle GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests? Android

Tags: java, android, http, restlet

I've a HTTP server running on my Android using `RESTlet`, works fine.

It is handling the URI as I want.

To do this I'm extending my classes to `Restlet`, I mean something like this:

```
public class PersonRestlet extends Restlet { (...) }
```

Again, this is working as expected.

Now I need to handle GET, POST, DELETE, PUT request but as far as I know the Restlet class can not handle it, am I write? I can only see/find the `public void handle(Request request, Response response)`.

From what I understood from examples and reading online I would need to extend `ServerResources` class and then use the `@Get`, `@Put`, etc to handle the GET, PUT, etc.

So my question is, how can I handle GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests just extending the `Restlet` class? Or a workaround would be nice as well.

PS; I know I can extend `ServerResources` instead of `Restlet` but I must avoid, at all cost, that due to the way the app is structured and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it, my workaround:

```
@Override
public void handle(Request request, Response response) {

    String type = request.getMethod().getName();
    String uid= (String) request.getAttributes().get("uid");

    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("get"))
    {
          (do you processing here)
    }
}
```